# Invalid OADate when using SUMX on a Date field from a Date Table

Tags: datetime, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Thanks for reading,

I have a DAX measure that finds the slope of some data over time.  To do this it needs to find the SUMX of a date field from a date table.

When I try to display only this sum, it comes back with an invalid OADate value error message:

Couldn't load the data for this visual

Invalid OADate value '7126785'.  Accepted values are between -657435.0 and 2958465.99999999

Here is the query I'm using:

```
measure =
VAR Known =
FILTER (
SELECTCOLUMNS (
ALLSELECTED ( 'Dates'[Date] ),
"Known[X]", 'Dates'[Date],
"Known[Y]", sum('table'[peoplecount])
),
AND (
NOT or(( ISBLANK ( Known[X] ) ),Known[X] = 0),
NOT or(( ISBLANK ( Known[Y] ) ),Known[Y] = 0)
)
)
VAR Count_Items =
COUNTROWS ( Known )
VAR Sum_X =
SUMX(Known,Known[X])
 
RETURN
Sum_X
```

My date table looks like this:

```
Date (Date) 
3/22/2020 
3/23/2020 
etc
```

My table containing data to be counted looks like this :
(This comes from direct query)

```
Date (Datetime),peoplecount (int)
3/21/2020 12:00:00 AM, 3 
3/22/2020 12:00:00 AM, 9
etc
```

Comment: Could you please share your table scructure with us and some sample data?

Comment: Thanks Aldert, I have included this above

Comment: Excuse me for asking but what is Known[X] and Known[Y]?

Comment: It's the name given for the object that stores the date and the peoplecount

Comment: My point is you do not explain how this relates to your data, are they calculated columns?

Comment: My end goal is to get my data to work with a DAX linear forecasting trend line (like in this post) : https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-to-create-a-Trend-line/td-p/398438